# xcode IBAction unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ibaction

i have a problem with and IBAction in my code. Everytime i click the button this Exception appears:

```
2013-01-15 22:25:00.798 FitnessApp[3478:c07] -[__NSCFString cancel:]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x93a7e50
2013-01-15 22:25:00.800 FitnessApp[3478:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString cancel:]: unrecognized selector sent to    instance 0x93a7e50'
```

i already searched for this error. however the solutions here on stackoverflow didnt work.
My connections are all correctly set. no dublicate connections or something like that.

My Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Placeholder_Description", nil)];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
    [self.buttonCancel setTarget:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel_Button", nil)];
    [self.buttonSave setTarget:NSLocalizedString(@"Save_Button", nil)];
    [self.textViewDescription.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [self.textViewDescription.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [self.textViewDescription.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [self.textViewDescription.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.textViewDescription setText:[self textViewDescriptionText]];
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate doSaveDescription:self withDescription:[self.textViewDescription text]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

i made some NSLogs to find out that the IBAction is the problem because there never was an output after clicking the buttons, just the exception.
So what can i do if the connections are correctly set?

Comment: I found out that the problem just appears with UIBarButtonItem not with normal buttons. if i connect normal buttons to my IBActions everything is fine. so why it doesnt work with UIBarButtonItems?

Comment: omg solved ..... setTitle not setTarget.....

Comment: You should answer your own question in case this may help someone else in the future :)